# Migrating from QuickReport to FastReport, Rave Reports or what?

Tags: delphi, migration, rave-reports, fastreport, quickreports

I'm migrating a Delphi project from old Delphi 2.0 IDE to the new RAD Studio XE2. I need to abandon QuickReport components. **To which free report component can I migrate to?**

I see XE2 has **FastReport** and **Rave Reports** included. Which one do you suggest me? Or are there other ones?

I look for **the easiest to convert to**, so the more similar to QuickReport I guess. In my project these QuickReport components are used:

```
TQRPreview
TQRBand
    TQRSysData
    TQRLabel
    TQRMemo
    TQRDBText
    TQRShape
TQuickReport
TQRDetailLink
```

I already tried some automatic converters, but they need to have QuickReport installed, which I don't have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading [this](http://rave-notes.blogspot.de/2010/02/time-to-say-goodbye.html) blog post, I wouldn't set on Rave for any new project.

Comment: According to the latest news on [their website](http://www.nevrona.com/news/upcoming.html), Nevrona will be attending DCon 2002 in June. I can't wait :o{

Comment: There's also their latest [announcements](http://www.nevrona.com/news/index.html). They've most recently released version 5.1.3 BEX on June 3rd, 2004. Yippee!

Comment: @KenWhite The odd thing is that in RAD Studio XE2 you find Rave Reports 10.0 BE included... Are they cheating me? :)

Comment: @bluish: Well, it's in fact in there. I  just think that Nevrona has stopped actively promoting it, and is basically just riding on their distribution with new versions of Delphi. I'm not sure if any new functionality has been added any time recently (D2009 and Unicode is the most recent I'm aware of), or if they're just re-numbering their version each time a new IDE is released and they add compatibility with it.

Comment: It's 2021 and I am still migrating Nevrona Rave Reports & QuickReports to FastReports. I have worked with QuickReports for 20 years and Rave Reports for 10 years. Stay away from QuickReports - new development hasn't taken place in the past 2 years and you wont find support for the latest version of Delphi 10.4 & 11. Rave Report support from Nevrona has been poor. A time saver is that FastReport does have a converter imports Rave Reports & QuickReports. The migration continues.